# How to change Unity2D aspect ratio with scenes?

Tags: aspect-ratio, unity-game-engine

I have multiple scenes in my mobile phone, in one scene the aspect ratio must be 16:10(vertical), in other scene it must be horizontal. I set the aspect ratio via Unity's GUI, but when I do this, the other scene is 16:10 too. Is there a way where I can change the aspect ratio, from the code? When that scene is loaded, the aspect ratio changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.LandscapeLeft;

Screen.orientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;
```

With these two codes I did, what I want to do. If the scene is playable horizontal, I used the first code, and for vertical, I used the second code. It worked like a charm

Answer (score 1):

So what you want to do is:

First go to this [Unity Docs link](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-CanvasScaler.html) and understand the use of canvas scaler and the options provided. Basically you can set the UI Scale Mode to `Scale with Screen Size` and set the resolution required.  In my case I set it to 1920x1080 (see image below) so that each screen has the same resolution across scenes.  Note that this must be applied to every canvas within the scenes.

---

[image: Canvas Scaler example]

---

This will allow you to configure any specific aspect ratio in terms of resolution across different scenes, as required.  I hope this helps.